# How to format strings that represent file paths on the local system

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript code that makes REST calls to the server and retrieve objects. These objects have a property called 'path' which refers to html files in the local file system. So I have an ancore tag like this

```
<a href="' + result.path +'" class="test">view</a>
```

which at runtime will replaced to something like

```
<a href="C:\Users\Tim\Downloads\0000048.html" class="test">view</a>
```

assuming we are on a windows system and the value of path is, C:\Users\Merylin\Downloads\0000048.html.

When I click on the link it navigates to C:\Users\Merylin\Downloads\0000048.html but I get an error response from the browser that, the address could not be identified. But when I reload the page it displays fine but I notice the address was changed to file:///C:\Users\Merylin\Downloads\0000048.html, **notice the additional file:///**. I don't want users to have to reload the page before it displays. I just want like to know if there are some javascript functions which I can use to format the path so that the browser can accept it. Note, I don't have any control over how that path is created, I just read it using REST and it may come from either windows or linux.

Comment: the path returned from your REST call must be the server path, i dont know what is your scenario, but how server can return the local path of the client machine?

Comment: I think its browser issue. Which browser you are getting error. I think it will work perfectly in chrome

Comment: @Yuva you were right. Its a browser issue. It works fine in chrome

Comment: @atul thanks for that point. I'll look into it and see if there is something i can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can append **"file:///"** before file path. User can get the page on single click.

I hope this will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

As Yuva says, to specify local path you must prepend "file:///" to the file path.

But it still won't work for you because most browsers, for security reasons, doesn't allow linking to local resources.

That is the error you are seeing at first try.

When you reload the page it works because the url it's already placed in the address bar thus "reloading" is much the same as manually writing the path and pressing "enter". Action which is always supposed to be done consciously and hence most browsers (those which supports local filesystem exploring) doesn't block it.

In summary, if you are forced to link local files, you will be forced to do that manual reload or, at most, use some browser plugin, like [Locallink for Firefox](http://locallink.mozdev.org/) to be able to open them directly (but, at least locallink, requires to use context menu option which, already, ensures you doesn't doing it by mistake. I don't know if there is other plugins that not).

But, anyway, if there is a chance that those files were available from the server, a much better solution is to serve from your application. For example with static router over a path holding the files if your server implementation is on Node + Express.